# Kubernetes Lifecycle Hooks

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

I would like to take particular actions when a K8 Pod, or the node its running on, crashes/restarts/etc -- basically notify another part of the application that this has happened. I also need this to be guaranteed to execute. Can a kubernetes [PreStop hook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/) accomplish this? From my understanding, these are generally used to gracefully shutdown containers when a pod is deleted and the hook handler is guaranteed to run. It seems like most people use them in scenarios where they are shutting things down themselves.

Will the hooks also run when a node unexpectedly crashes? If not, is there a kubernetes solution for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

PreStop hook doesn't work for nodes. PreStop hook is a task running during termination of containers and is executing specific command or HTTP request against a specific endpoint on the Container.

If you are interested in health monitoring of nodes, you may read about 
[node-problem-detector](https://github.com/kubernetes/node-problem-detector) already installed by default to [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io) in [GCE](https://cloud.google.com/).